# UseQuery doesn't work after redirect with useMutations by apollo react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

After useMutation, user go to other page.

There are useQuery, but it doesn't work.

```
export default () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [getStockMutation] = useMutation(getStock, {
    variables: { click: click },
    onCompleted({ getStockMutation }) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        history.push("/home");
      }, 500);
    },
  });

  const onClick = async () => {
    setClick(true);
    try {
      await getStockMutation();
    } catch (e) {
      toast.error("아이디와 비밀번호를 다시 확인 해 보세요.");
    }
  };
```

this is mutation page. if user click button, getStockMutation is work.
if getStockMutation is completed, go to "/home"

```
export default () => {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(allStock);
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.allstock.length === 0) {
      history.push(`/getAccount`);
    }
  }, [data, history]);
```

this is useQuery page(home). there are useQuery(allStock) but it doesn't work.
console.log show {allstock:Array(0)},
i check it in localhost:8000/grahpql,

```
{
  "data": {
    "allstock": [
      {
        "id": "57",
        "stockname": "LX세미콘"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i check network,only mutation(getStock) communication work, but useQuery(allStock) communication not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fix it. it works. I add fetchPolicy to useQuery.

```
export default () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(allStock, {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(data, loading, error);
```